# Vim :Ag search and replace, globally and within a directory

Tags: vim

I am using :Ag in vim to search for patterns, but I can't figure out how to search and replace through ALL files in my project, or within a directly that I specify. How is this done?

Comment: I brewed my plugin [ctrlsf.vim](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) to do the job.

Comment: Isn't the Linux command of sed designed to do just this kind of operation (without even opening any of the files)? What is the point of using Ag or any combination of Vim commands to emulate sed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Vim, project-wide *search* and *replace* is at best a two-step process unless you install a plugin that abstracts those two steps for you like [EasyGrep.](https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep)

In its most basic form, project-wide search/replace looks like this:

```
:args `grep -nl foo *.js`
:argdo %s/foo/bar/c
```

It won't help you much with `:Ag`, though, because Vim doesn't have a built-in command similar to the `:*do` family that works on the quickfix list.

Drew Neil has a couple of screencasts, [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/) and [there](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/), that deal with project-wide search/replace. The `:Qfdo` command mentionned at the bottom of the second post is specifically geared toward `:vimgrep`/`:Ack`/`:Ag` users. With [that command](https://github.com/DouglasRoyds/vimrc/blob/master/plugin/qfdo.vim) and `:Ag`, the two-step process becomes:

```
:Ag foo
:Qfdo s/foo/bar/c
```

---

-- EDIT --

Vim now has `:cdo`, `:cfdo`, `:ldo`, `:lfdo`.

Comment: An example using `:cdo`: `:cdo s/foo/bar/g`

Answer (score 0):

In `vim`, there are multiple solutions, but you have to open all the files in order to be able to do this. You can open the files in different windows, buffers or tabs, and for all the options, you have a method to operate on all files:

```
:windo :Ag
```

or

```
:bufdo :Ag
```

or

```
:tabdo :Ag
```

See `:help windows`, `:help buffers` or `:help tab-page-commands` for more info.